# How to intercede on create action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have this action to create an object.

```
def create 
  @campaign = Campaign.create(params[:campaign])
  respond_with(@campaign)
end
```

Since I'm using `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` to create an autocomplete for users to type in the username, I'm receiving the username as string and I'll need it to convert to id to save it as `user_id:integer`.

I'm not sure how to run code before the `create` action is triggered.

Comment: What parameter do you receive the username in?

Comment: "user_id"=>"myusername",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `before_filter` method, provided by Rails.

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :intercede, only: :create

  # some other actions here

  def create 
    @campaign = Campaign.create(params[:campaign])
    respond_with(@campaign)
  end

  private

  def intercede
    # let's do some hacking with params here
  end
end
```

Comment: A nice clean way to separate out the 'params' processing. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can create getter and setter methods in your User model that looks up the user on assignment, something like this:

```
def username
  user.name
end

def username=(name)
  self.user = User.find_by_name(name)
end
```

Just make sure that :username is included if you use attr_accesible in your User model.

Also to clarify, this example is dependent on that the jquery form field is using the name username

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the params in your create method like this:

```
def create 
  # preprocess params
  user = User.find_by_name(params[:campaign][:user_id])
  params[:campaign][:user_id] = user.id
  # Now create the record
  @campaign = Campaign.create(params[:campaign])
  respond_with(@campaign)
end
```

But as mentioned by gmile, it is better to do this processing of params in :before_filter.